# IMG Class not applying

Tags: html, css

So I'm attempting to cause an image to float to the left, and round the corners.

This however does not seem to work for me. It should work as I've performed this successfully previously.

**Relevant HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <img class="left rounded-corners" alt="REDACTED" src="REDACTED" width="320" height="186" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

**Relevant CSS**

```
.container {}

.left {
float: left;
}

.right {
float: right;
}

img {
display: block;
}

.img-left {
float: left;
}

.img-right {
float: right;
}

.img-rounded-corners {
border-radius: 10px;
}

.rounded-corners {
border-radius: 10px;
}

.row {
display: block;
}
```

**Full Code**

**FULL HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Project Crazy | BETA 1</title>

  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

  <meta name="description" content="Project Crazy | Under Construction">
  <meta name="author" content="James Timms">

  <!-- Required StyleSheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700|Luckiest+Guy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Meera Inimai' rel='stylesheet'>

  <!-- jQuery Library -->
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Navigation Bar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-blue navbar-dark fixed-top" style="text-align: right; padding-top: 0.1vh; padding-bottom: 0.1vh; font-family: 'Luckiest Guy';">

    <a class="navbar-brand" style="font-size: 2vh;" href="#">
      <img src="logo.png" alt="Project Crazy" style="width:40px;">
    </a>

    <!-- NavBar Links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" style="font-size: 2vh;" href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" style="font-size: 2vh;" href="#">Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" style="font-size: 2vh;" href="#">Link 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </nav>

  <div class="space1" style="padding-bottom: 20vh;"></div>
  <div class="card" style="max-width: 50%; margin: auto;">
    <div class="card bg-info text-white" style="font-size: 25px; font-family: 'Luckiest Guy';">
      <center>Welcome To Project Crazy!</center>
    </div>

    <div class="card-body" style="font-family: 'Meera Inimai';">
      Project Crazy is the number one resource for ToonTown: Corporate Clash! More resources are added constantly, so make sure you visit frequently to see if anything changes!
      <br />
      <br />
      <div class="header">What's on Offer?</div>
      Here at Project Crazy, you can do many, many things! Here are a few of the main attractions!
      <br />

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <img class="left rounded-corners" alt="invasion tracker" src="https://toonhq.org/static/2.4.3/img/home/invasions.jpg" width="320" height="186" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="clear: both;"></div>


    </div>
    <div class="card-footer"></div>
  </div>


  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="page-footer font-small bg-blue fixed-bottom ml-auto">

    <!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="footer-copyright">© 2018 Copyright [ Team Crazy ]
    </div>
    <!-- Copyright -->

  </footer>
  <!-- Footer -->
</body>

</html>
```

**FULL CSS**

```
/* Parallax Scrolling Blurred Background */

body {
  margin: 0vh;
  padding-top: 0vh;
  padding-bottom: 0vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body::before {
  background: url('../img/bg.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  -moz-filter: blur(0px);
  -o-filter: blur(0px);
  -ms-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}

/* width */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0vh;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

/* Track */

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

/* Handle */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #3399FF;
}

.bg-blue {
  background-color: #3399FF !important
}

a.bg-dark:focus, a.bg-dark:hover, button.bg-dark:focus, button.bg-dark:hover     {
  background-color: #1d2124 !important
}

.page-footer {
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 0.2vh;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 178vh;
  padding-bottom: 0.2vh;
}

.footer-copyright {
  font-family: 'Luckiest Guy';
  font-size: 1.4vh;
  color: #fff;
}

.header {
  font-family: 'Luckiest Guy';
  font-size: 2.5vh;
}

.container {}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.img-left {
  float: left;
}

.img-right {
  float: right;
}

.img-rounded-corners {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.rounded-corners {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.row {
  display: block;
}
```

Hopefully somebody can figure out why this is not working, as it has been provided that this should work. I'm not exactly new to HTML & CSS. I have tested this before, and it should work, it's just with this one I am a tad stumped.

Comment: can you clarify, 'does not seem to work for me' ? You may not be getting your expected output by including `img { display: block; }` but the image is left-aligned and has rounded corners based on the code you provided.

Comment: Well none of the classes apply at all. The image isn't rounded, and it doesn't align it.

Comment: you may not correctly loading the css file (guessing maybe it is external?). Works for me when including in `<style>` block within same file as html.

Comment: The CSS file loads fine as everything else within the stylesheet works fine, I have custom navigation bars, custom scroll bar, and custom background-image, which all work fine.

Comment: I copied your exact code to codepen here (I just added a test image) and it works so the css is not being loaded or there's something else interfering https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QxRbPm

Comment: I will post the full code as an EDIT

Comment: Works fine in jsfiddle too
https://jsfiddle.net/3ocsb97p/3/

Comment: Full Code has been posted

Comment: I would say you have a conflict somewhere. If you're using firefox you could use the inspect element tool to see what's happening fully.

Comment: I have a small feeling it's to do with Bootstrap 4.
However, my CSS should override Bootstrap's CSS.

Comment: In Chrome, right click on the image and select "Inspect". In the developer tools, in the "Styles" tab, look to see what's overriding your styles. (It may be that you are including main.css BEFORE you include Bootstrap, so in that case, Bootstrap may be overwriting your styles ... so try loading main.css after Bootstrap and see if that fixes it)

Comment: Have you tried - just as a test - to rename you class names see if anything happens? Like container-test, row-test etc...

Comment: @emmzee I changed the positioning, this actually broke the layout of my site, as it's heavily bootstrap orientated, and not so much my main.css.

However, this didn't fix the image. I did inspect, however nothing seems to be overriding the styles.

Comment: @FoxyFish I renamed it to Page-Footer which broke the site, did not work

Comment: Seems to work - even with your updated code. I replaced the Bootstrap reference with the cdn version. Image is aligned left and has rounded corners. Not sure why you're not seeing styles.

Comment: Did you change it in both the html and css?

Comment: Side note: your `.row` will be overridden by Bootstrap and you can use `.rounded` and `.float-left` / `.float-right` utility classes to eliminate a good amount of unnecessary custom css.

Comment: Found this.

I went into the bootstrap CSS file, and moved the CSS over to my main.css so that I can manage it easier.

Cheers all :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <img class="img-rounded" alt="REDACTED" src="REDACTED" width="320" height="186" />
</div>
```

as "img-rounded" class is used in bootstrap to make it corners round then in css you can add float:left to this class like:

`.img-rounded {
float:left;
}`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: ( I used Ayush's html code )

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <img class="img-rounded" alt="REDACTED" src="REDACTED" width="320" height="186" />
</div>
```

with styles

```
.img-rounded{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: 1. img.rounded isn't part of Bootstrap 4
2. I can't really do this, I need to use two separate classes. One for float left, and one for rounded. Due to the fact I am going to be having multiple images using rounded edges, some floating right.

Comment: I just use that name and you can whatever the name you want. My main idea was to point you to the `position` style property. :D